# Could Linux kernel load and run another Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot

I wish to load Linux kernel from USB device that make some actions and load another kernel from HDD. It is possible to force kernel to give control to another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [kexec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) does this, and many servers do this for failsafe booting

Comment: With some limitations. If you run on 32-bit system with EFI it's not possible to get it in the second kernel. Basically it looses pointers to ACPI, EFI, DMI.